# Сортировка текстового поля как числа и как строки одновременно?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

В GridView вывожу данные из таблицы.

Есть поле `Номер` - текстовый тип. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сортировать это поле в БД MySql одновременно как число и строку.

К примеру:

```
1, 2, Поле, Номер, 10, 15
```

А получить после сортировки

> ```
> 1, 2, 10, 15, Номер, Поле
> ```

Comment: Т.е. вначале числа, а потом строки?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SELECT x FROM y ORDER BY CAST(z -1 AS UNSIGNED);

WHERE x - needed params,
y - name of table
z - sort column

Comment: Все будет работать, пока в таблице нет отрицательных чисел или 0

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, да, правда, но мы же не выходим за рамки поставленной задачи сейчас, нужно будет учитывать это - можно будет изменить тип.

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот таким запросом

```
select
  f1
from t1
order by
  if(cast(f1 + 0 as char) = f1, 0, 1),
  f1 + 0,
  f1
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc23f/4)

Выражение `f1 +  0` вернет значение `f1` если значение представимо числом или `0`. Соответственно `if(cast(f1 + 0 as char) = f1, 0, 1)` вернет `0` для числовых значений и `1` для нечисловых. Отсортировав по такому выражению мы получим первыми числовые выражения, а потом нечисловые

Затем отсортируем по выражению `f1 + 0`. Это отсортирует группу числовых значений.

Ну и в конце сортируем оставшиеся строки по выражению `f1`